# How I store the input.value of two or more dynamic inputs and, with a radio input, select one of all dynamic inputs and store it separately?

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I want the Buddy Level [ i ] to be stored outside the iteration and also if it has the active radio input selected, stored separately. Something like "Active buddy Level = X" and "Buddy nº [ i ] Level = Y"

```js
//buddy input
let buddy = document.getElementById("companion")
//buddy lvl inputs
let buddyResult = document.getElementById("companion-inputs")
//funcion que crea inputs dinámicos (text + radio)
function createResult(){
  buddyResult.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= buddy.value; i++) {
    const element = buddy.value[i];
    buddyResult.innerHTML +=
     `<div class= "lvl-check">
     <input class="clases" id="companion-${i}" type="number" placeholder="Buddy nº${i} lvl"/>
     <input type="radio" name="active" />
     <label for="companion-${i}">active</label>
     </div>`;
  }
}
```

```css
.lvl-check{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.clases{
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!--al poner un número, se generan X inputs-->
<input onchange="createResult()" class="clases" id="companion" type="number" placeholder=" Nº of buddies"/>

<!--aqui dentro  se generan los inputs dinámicos con los radio-->
<div id="companion-inputs">
</div>
```

Comment: can I edit my post?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script code:

```
let buddy = document.getElementById("companion");
      let buddyResult = document.getElementById("companion-inputs");
      let results = {};
      let count = 0;

      function getResult(id) {
        let el = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
        results[id] = el.value;
      }

      function createResult(event) {
        console.log("results", results);
        for (let i = 1; i <= buddy.value; i++) {
          count++;
          const element = buddy.value[i];
          buddyResult.innerHTML += `<div id="lvl-check">
            <input class="clases" id="${count}"
              onchange="getResult(${count})"
              value="${results[count]}"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Buddy ${i} level"
            />
            <input type="radio" name="${count}" />
            <label for="${count}">active</label>
          </div>`;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `data-something` attribute to the radio so you can identify its corresponding input. I also refactored my solution a little so you can print or pass the value of a radio using a callback.

```js
let buddy = document.getElementById("companion")
let buddyResult = document.getElementById("companion-inputs")

function createResult() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= buddy.value; i++) {
    const element = buddy.value[i];
    buddyResult.innerHTML += `<div id="lvl-check"><input class="clases" id="companion-${i}" type="number" placeholder="Buddy ${i} level"/><input type="radio" name="active" data-companion-id="companion-${i}"/><label for="companion-${i}">active</label></div>`
  }
  document.querySelectorAll("#companion-inputs [type=radio]").forEach(function(radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      get_value(this, console.log)
    });
  })
}

function get_values() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#companion-inputs [type=radio]").forEach(function(radio) {
    console.log(get_value(radio));
  })
}

function get_value(radio, foo) {
  var id = radio.getAttribute('data-companion-id');
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (typeof foo === 'function') {
    foo(value)
  }
  return value;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="createResult()" class="clases" id="companion" type="number" placeholder="Amount of gardening companions" />
<div id="companion-inputs"></div>
<button onclick="get_values()">print values</button>
```